# Props values not rendering in vuejs

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5.3, vue-component, vue.js

I am trying to create an ajax form component in vuejs in Laravel 5.3 application. But, I guess, I have stuck in displaying the form fields. Can anybody help me out?

The front end to render the form:

```
<ajax-form
    :autocomplete=false
    :schema="[{
        label: 'Username:',
        type: 'text',
        id: 'username',
        name: 'username',
        placeholder: 'Eg. johndoe',
        inputClass: 'input is-info',
        model: 'username',
        required: true,
    }, {
        label: 'Email:',
        type: 'email',
        id: 'email',
        name: 'email',
        placeholder: 'Eg. johndoe@example.com',
        inputClass: 'input is-info',
        model: 'email',
        required: true,
    }, {
        label: 'Password',
        type: 'password',
        id: 'password',
        name: 'password',
        placeholder: 'Eg. password',
        inputClass: 'input is-info',
        model: 'password',
        required: true,
    }, {
        label: 'Confirm Password',
        type: 'password',
        id: 'confirm_password',
        name: 'confirm_password',
        placeholder: 'Eg. password',
        inputClass: 'input is-info',
        model: 'confirm_password',
        required: true,
    }]"
></ajax-form>
```

And the `template` in AjaxForm.vue file:

```
<form method="POST">
    <div v-for="field in schema">
        <label class="label">{{ field.label }}</label>
        <p class="control">
            <input
                type="field.type"
                name="field.name"
                id="field.id"
                class="field.inputClass"
                placeholder="field.placeholder"
                required="field.required"
                v-model="field.model"
            >
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the content of the `script` tag:

```
<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            autocomplete: Boolean,
            schema: Array
        }
    }
</script>
```

The issue is that, the form fields are not rendering correctly. See the image:[image]

And what I want is:
[image]

**P.S.:** I have just started learning about the components, so, this might a silly mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting literal values inside your loop, you need to use `v-bind:` or the shorthand `:`:

```
<input
  :type="field.type"
  :name="field.name"
  :id="field.id"
  :class="field.inputClass"
  :placeholder="field.placeholder"
  :required="field.required"
  v-model="field.model"
/>
```

**EDIT**

You cannot bind `v-model` that way, instead you will need to bind it to data. The easiest way is to create a values array and then set it up in your created hook of your component. Vue doesn't bind to arrays directly, so you have to push an object onto the array:

```
created() {
  this.inputs.forEach((input) => {
    // push new value object to array
    this.values.push({value: input.value})    
  });
},
data() {
  return {
    values: []
  }
}
```

Now, inside your `v-for` you can bind you inputs to the values with index:

```
  <div v-for="(input, index) in inputs">
    <input  v-model="values[index].value" />
  </div>
```

And here's the working JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/xsg91o04/

Comment: Tried that as well.. The form cannot be shown at all.. It just disappears.

Comment: Are you getting any error in the console? It looks like you are modifying a prop directly.

Comment: Yeah.. The error is shown in my terminal and not in chrome's console.. Here's the error message: `template syntax error <input :type="field.type" v-model="field.model">:
v-model does not support dynamic input types. Use v-if branches instead.
`

Comment: What version of vue are you using?

Comment: The version of Vue.js is 2.0.3

Comment: I've updated my answer which will hopefully point you in the right direction